# Can anyone explain me Python for loop (or iteration) algorithm

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am learning python from Coursera . I have written one program , According to that when I click on the screen , it draws circle . See the program below  --

```
# Dots

# importing
import simplegui
import math

width = 600
height = 600
ball_list = []
radius = 20
colour = "Yellow"

# position ditector
def distance(p,q) :
    return math.sqrt((p[0]-q[0])**2 + (p[1]-q[1])**2)



# Mouse click -- Change the position
def click(pos) :
    ball_list.append(pos)
#    global position
#   global colour
#    if  distance(pos, position) < radius :
#        colour = "Blue"
#    else :
#        position = list(pos)
#        colour = "Yellow"


# Drawing the ball
def draw(canvas) :
    for position in ball_list :
        canvas.draw_circle(position , radius , 2, "Black" , colour)

# Creating the frame
frame = simplegui.create_frame("Dots" , 600,600)
frame.set_canvas_background("White")

frame.set_draw_handler(draw)

# mouse click 
frame.set_mouseclick_handler(click)


# Start
frame.start()
```

But my doubt is in def draw(canvas), `for position in ball_list` , I have not defined any position . I made `position = list(pos)` as comment . Then what is the value of position in `position in ball_list` , How can for loop work without any value ? What is iteration ? What is the difference between for loop and iteration ?

If above code doesn't work in your IDE, please go to http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user38_VSZ0jZ0uTh_0.py
and run it .

Comment: Because it's an iterator.

Comment: Can you explain me How

Comment: I suggest you go through the excellent Python tutorial (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/). From start to finish it does not take too much of your time and is definitely worth it.

Answer (score 1):

`for` loop in python is little bit different compared to other languages. I'll try explaining with code you have written.Every time you call the `click` function then you are appending the `pos` to the list called `ball_list` which you need to draw the circle.

```
def click(pos) :
    ball_list.append(pos) ## appends the pos to ball_list
```

Now after you have list with `pos` then you call the following function.

```
def draw(canvas) :
    for position in ball_list :
        canvas.draw_circle(position , radius , 2, "Black" , colour)
```

Here the variable `position` iterates through all the `pos` that you have appended to the list `ball_list` starting from first till last value.
And if you are wondering how and what is the value of `position` variable then print it's value and see it for yourself like the following:

```
def draw(canvas) :
        for position in ball_list :
            print position  ## prints one pos value in the ball_list for each iteration.
            canvas.draw_circle(position , radius , 2, "Black" , colour)
```

Answer (score 0):

In python, `for x in y:` iterates through every item in `y`, and assigns the value of the current iteration to the variable `x` so that you can reference that value inside the body of the for loop. [Here's an eval.in](https://eval.in/209259) that might help you see how it works.

[image: Screenshot of the eval.in]

Here's a brief comparison to Java, assuming that the variable "arrayList" is an `ArrayList` (Java) or `list` (Python) of things, and you want to call the method `do_something_with()` on each value in the list.

Python:

```
for x in arrayList:
    do_something_with(x)
```

Java:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
    do_something_with(arrayList.get(i));
}
```

Fundamentally, you COULD write Python that looks more like the Java:

```
for x in range(0, len(arrayList)):
    do_something_with(arrayList[x])
```

This code would do the exact same thing. However, Python realized that this is a common enough task that there was value in providing a level of abstraction for it (often called ["syntactic sugar"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) in programming languages). You can read more about Python iterators, and how different kinds of data get iterated, in the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#iterators).

Comment: Can you explain me with some simple example

Comment: Do you know any other programming languages? Perhaps it would be easier to compare to one of those. There's also [a section in the python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#iterators) that will show you how different kinds of python data are iterated.

Comment: I have some Java experience . Can't go to that link ---  403 Forbidden

Request forbidden by administrative rules.

Comment: There's also --- a section in the python documentation --- that will , that "a section in the python documentation" link , I am in India , In my country I think I can't access that :(

Comment: It's just the official Python Documentation. Maybe try [this link](http://python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/classes.html#iterators) instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
a_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

for x in [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]:
    print x
```

10
20
30
40
50

```
for x in a_list:
   print x
```

1
2
3
4
5
6
7

```
for i in range(10):
    print i
```

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

Answer (score 0):

Say you have your own class that you want it to be iterable:

```
 class MyRange(object):
     def __init__(self, low, high):
         self.low = low
         self.high = high

     def __iter__(self):
         low = self.low
         while self.high >= low:
             yield low
             low += 1
```

Now you can:

```
r = MyRange(1, 10)
for number in r:
    print number,
```

`number` now have the value returned from `__iter__` in each iteration. That's how things work in Python, and in your case, you have a `list`, which has it's own `__iter__` and used in a similar way.